# How to enable a button if not all required fields are filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

None of the "Similar quiestons" helped me

I have a button that I need to disable once it was clicked:

```
<button class="button" type="submit" id="saveButton" hidden="hidden" style="display:none">submit</button>
<input onclick="validator()" id="handleSaveButton" class="button" type="button" value="my button value">
```

Here's how I do it:

```
function validator(){
    $(".buttons :input[value:'my button value']").prop("disabled",true)
    ...
    //something else goes here
    ...
    document.getElementById("saveButton").click();
}
```

Now this works but my page also has required fields. And if those aren't filled, you have to refresh the whole page to make save button available again.

I'm looking for a solution to

- Make my button disabled once clicked
- Make it enabled again if required fields are not filled

Thanks. Please note that I cannot change the structure with hidden submit and actual button

Comment: Call `checkValidity` to check if your form is currently in a valid state, _before_ you disable your button. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#validating_forms_using_javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of complicated selector inside JQuery. Just differ elements by className: **.buttons.handler** And **.buttons.save**.

```
<button class="buttons save" type="submit" id="saveButton" style="display:none"> submit </button>
<input onclick="validator()" id="handleSaveButton" class="buttons handler" type="button" value="my button value"/>
```

After that, you can write this simple JS code. And don't forget, jQuery always return a collection of objects with a length. That's why i used **$()[0]** to handle the first element.

```
function validator(){
    const btnHandler = $(".buttons.handler")[0];
    $(btnHandler).attr('disabled',true);
      //

    const btnSave = $(".buttons.save")[0];
    $(btnSave).css({ display: "block" });
    btnSave.click();
  }
```

Please Don't forget to mark as solved

Comment: How does this help me with my problem? I need the button to be disabled on click. If any required fields are empty I need the button to be available

Comment: So, provide more informations. My answer is based on how you submitted your case

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted an answer but it got deleted unfortunately.
Here's their solution:

```
var requiredFields = document.querySelectorAll("[required]");
var allFilled = true;
requiredFields.forEach(function(field) {
    if (field.value.trim() === '') {
        allFilled = false;
        return false; // to break out of the forEach loop
    }
});

if (allFilled) {
    $(".buttons :input[value:'my button value']").prop("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("saveButton").click();
}
```

Worked great for me